# How to apply a row-varying multiplier on specific columns of a large DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame of the form:

```
   c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
0   A    1    7   13   19
1   B    2    8   14   20
2   A    3    9   15   21
3   B    4   10   16   22
4   B    5   11   17   23
5   C    6   12   18   24
```

For each value in column 1 I have a corresponding multiplier in a dictionary of the form:

```
{'A':10, 'B':100, 'C':1000, 'D':10000} Where 'D' might not exist in the DataFrame above
```

For each row I want to multiply the elements by the appropriate multiplier *except* for elements in specific columns. In this example we'll pick columns 1 and 5 as the excluded columns for this representative case. The result should look something like this:

```
   c1      c2      c3      c4   c5
0   A      10      70     130   19
1   B     200     800    1400   20
2   A      30      90     150   21
3   B     400    1000    1600   22
4   B     500    1100    1700   23
5   C    6000   12000   18000   24
```

In reality, my dataset has a couple dozen columns (small enough that I could manually list the filtered/unfiltered columns), but *hundreds of thousands of rows*. The dictionary containing the multipliers is smaller, but still several thousand key:value pairs long.

I've struggled to work out a fast solution to this problem using `multiply`, and iteration becomes very time consuming for the quantity of data I'm working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`multiply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html):

```
dic = {'A':10, 'B':100, 'C':1000, 'D':10000}

# update IN PLACE
df.update(df.drop(columns=['c1', 'c5']).mul(df['c1'].map(dic), axis=0))
```

Or:

```
dic = {'A':10, 'B':100, 'C':1000, 'D':10000}

cols = df.columns.difference(['c1', 'c5'])
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df['c1'].map(dic), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
  c1    c2     c3     c4  c5
0  A    10     70    130  19
1  B   200    800   1400  20
2  A    30     90    150  21
3  B   400   1000   1600  22
4  B   500   1100   1700  23
5  C  6000  12000  18000  24
```